# Why count ignores grouping by

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, case, postgresql-9.4

I don't understand why my query doesn't group results of count by the column I specified. Instead it counts all occurrences of outcome_id in the 'un' subtable.

What am I missing there?

The full structure of my sample database and the query I tried are here:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4HuLpTFWaE2yBSQSzf3dX4/4

```
CREATE TABLE combination (
    combination_id integer,
    ticket_id integer,
    outcomes integer[]
);
CREATE TABLE outcome (
outcome_id integer,
ticket_id integer,
val double precision
);

insert into combination 
values
(510,188,'{52,70,10}'),
(511,188,'{52,56,70,18,10}'),
(512,188,'{55,70,18,10}'),
(513,188,'{54,71,18,10}'),

(514,189,'{52,54,71,18,10}'),
(515,189,'{55,71,18,10,54,56}')
;

insert into outcome
values
(52,188,1.3),
(70,188,2.1),
(18,188,2.6),
(56,188,2),
(55,188,1.1),
(54,188,2.2),
(71,188,3),
(10,188,0.5),

(54,189,2.2),
(71,189,3),
(18,189,2.6),
(55,189,2)

with un AS (
      SELECT combination_id, unnest(outcomes) outcome
      FROM combination c JOIN
           outcome o
           on o.ticket_id = c.ticket_id
      GROUP BY 1,2
     ) 
SELECT combination_id, cnt
FROM (SELECT un.combination_id,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN o.val >= 1.3 THEN 1 END) as cnt
      FROM un JOIN
           outcome o
           on o.outcome_id = un.outcome 
      GROUP BY 1
     ) x
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY  1
```

Expected result should be:

```
510 2
511 4
512 2
513 3
514 4
515 4
```

Comment: The table definitions should be in your question, not only in a fiddle that requires to execute scripts from multiple sources.

Comment: Ok, post updated

Comment: Could you explain, in plain English, what you are trying to count, exactly? `514 4` in the "expected result" does not seem to add up. Should be `514 3`, right? The best query depends on *actual* table definitions also showing ***constraints*** (most importantly PK, FK, UNIQUE) and information about data distribution ...

Comment: Now I realized I missed few entries in outcome table for combinations 514 and 515, that's why there was a difference. I'll update my post and check your answer tomorrow as it's not comfortable from mobile. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join on `ticket_id` also:

```
with un AS (
      SELECT c.combination_id, c.ticket_id, unnest(c.outcomes) outcome
      FROM combination c JOIN outcome o
      on o.ticket_id = c.ticket_id
      GROUP BY 1,2,3
     ) 
SELECT combination_id, cnt
FROM (SELECT un.combination_id, un.ticket_id,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN o.val >= 1.3 THEN 1 END) as cnt
      FROM un JOIN outcome o
      on o.outcome_id = un.outcome and o.ticket_id = un.ticket_id 
      GROUP BY 1,2
     ) x
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY  1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=e303b36a00e0dcaf4b8e93565c5c2ee3).
Results:

```
> combination_id | cnt
> -------------: | --:
>            510 |   2
>            511 |   4
>            512 |   2
>            513 |   3
>            514 |   3
>            515 |   4
```

Comment: Thanks! , despite I missed few entries in outcome table for combinations 514 and 515 your answer counts correctly :) However it is highly confusing for me. Why it requires less strict grouping to count as I expected? Putting it simple - one ticket can have multiple combinations but specific combination_id can be on only one ticket so what's the point of necessity to include ticket ID too?

Comment: *Why it requires less strict grouping to count as I expected?* it requires more strict grouping, this is what the extra condition does. It matches the tickets too. Without it there are combinations that you don't want to be counted.

Comment: I don't get it, why without joining `ticket_id` it counts records from other combinations while it should by already grouped by them as I used `group by combination_id`? Why `ticket_id` changes so much if there are repeating outcomes within one ticket but different combinations? Please explain me this somehow step by step because that's at this point illogical for me

Comment: This all has to do with the rows fetched before the grouping. When you have only `on o.outcome_id = un.outcome` there are more rows with combinations that should not be counted, meaning combinations that belong to different tickets. When you set the correct condition for the join: `on o.outcome_id = un.outcome and o.ticket_id = un.ticket_id` you get less rows, so restrict the combinations to only the valid ones. Then you apply grouping which counts the valid rows.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming**, you have these PK constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE combination (
  combination_id integer PRIMARY KEY
, ticket_id      integer
, outcomes       integer[]
);

CREATE TABLE outcome (
  outcome_id integer
, ticket_id  integer
, val        double precision
, PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id, outcome_id)
);
```

and **assuming** this objective:

***For each row in table `combination`, count the number of array elements in `outcomes` for which there is at least one row with matching `outcome_id` and `ticket_id` in table `outcome` - and `val >= 1.3`.***

Assuming above PK, this burns down to a much simpler query:

```
SELECT c.combination_id, count(*) AS cnt
FROM   combination c
JOIN   outcome     o USING (ticket_id)
WHERE  o.outcome_id = ANY (c.outcomes)
AND    o.val >= 1.3
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This alternative might be faster with index support:

```
SELECT c.combination_id, count(*) AS cnt
FROM   combination c
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL unnest(c.outcomes) AS u(outcome_id)
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT
   FROM   outcome o
   WHERE  o.outcome_id = u.outcome_id
   AND    o.val >= 1.3
   AND    o.ticket_id  = c.ticket_id   -- ??
   )
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Plus, it does not require the PK on `outcome`. Any number of matching rows still count as *1*, due to `EXISTS`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=67c79975c2b2e44ff026cb1dbf72ae92)*

As always, the best answer depends on the *exact* definition of setup and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version of @forpas answer:

-- You don't need to join to outcomes in the "with" statement.

```
with un AS (
SELECT combination_id, ticket_id, unnest(outcomes) outcome
FROM combination c
-- no need to join to outcomes here

GROUP BY 1,2,3
) 

SELECT combination_id, cnt FROM 
(
SELECT un.combination_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN o.val >= 1.3 THEN 1 END) as cnt

FROM un
JOIN outcome o on o.outcome_id = un.outcome
            and o.ticket_id = un.ticket_id

GROUP BY 1
)x

GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY  1
```

As others have pointed out, the expected result for 514 should be 3 based on your input data.

I'd also like to suggest that using full field names in the group by and order by clauses makes queries easier to debug and maintain going forward.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I missed few entries in outcome table for combinations 514 and 515, anyway your answers counts correctly. However it is highly confusing for me. Why it requires less strict grouping to count as I expected? Putting it simple - one ticket can have multiple combinations but specific `combination_id` can be on only one ticket so what's the point of necessity to include ticket ID too?

Comment: I moved the join on ticket_id to the lower select statement.  The with clause is used to unnest the outcomes only.